# vue.js how do I make a v-slot template dynamic?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-slot

Hello and thank you for reading my question! I am working with Vue.js, Vuetify and v-data-table and I am working on making my v-slot work with two different strings as the name of the header.

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-data-table
      :options="data"
      :headers="headers"
      :items="data
      :server-items-length="40"
      :loading="loading"
      :multi-sort="true"
      @update:options="updateThePage"
    >
      <template v-slot:[`header.overalls`]="{ header }" class="flight-date-header">
        <overallDatePicker
          :options="data"
        />
        {{ header.name }}
      </template>

      <template v-slot:[`item.name`]="{ item }">
        <p class="company-name">
          {{ item.companyName }}
        </p>
      </template>

      <template v-slot:[`item.price`]="{ item }">
          <p> {{ item.price }} </p>
      </template>

      <template v-slot:[`item.flightDate`]="{ item }">
        <p class="style">
          {{ item.startDate }}
        </p>
      </template>

    </v-data-table>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

and I store my headers like below

```
headers: [
      { text: 'Campaign Name', value: 'overalls' },
    ],
```

Ideally I would like the name of this slot

```
<template v-slot:[`header.overalls`]="{ header }" class="flight-date-header">
       <overallDatePicker
         :options="data"
       />
     </template>
```

To work with two different data options. right now the name of the header is overalls but I want the name of the header so `['header.overalls']` to be like `['header.('overalls' || 'shoes')]` ,

**The reason** I am doing this is right now when I click on the header the options.sortBy property of the table gets set to 'overalls', but I want the icon on the column to show up if the options.sortBy property of the table is "overalls" and also show up if it is "shoes"

Please help and thank you so much!

Comment: So are you trying to make your component work with two different column configurations ?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I want to do

Comment: well, actually you don't. You want to use same header slot content for two different columns in the same table. Which is a very different thing...

Answer (score 5):

To reuse the slot content for multiple headers/columns, use Vue's [dynamic slots names](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Dynamic-Slot-Names) feature + `v-for`

```js
data() {
  return {
    specialHeaders: ['overalls', 'shoes'],
  }
}
```

```html
<template v-for="column in specialHeaders" v-slot:[`header.${column}`]="{ header }">
  Special:{{header.text}}
</template>
```

Comment: I actually need the column to work with two different column configurations at the same time, so I need it to work with 'overalls' and also work with 'shoes'

Comment: Those are columns in the same table ?